# Dispatcher for a JSON API without routes

Tags: php, performance, reflection, controller, url-routing

I am using this code for a fast JSON API without routes.

Does this code contain any useless parts?  Is the class loader efficient enough? Are there any better options? Is `ReflectionMethod` slow if used once?

```
<?php

/*
 * Init stuff
 */

session_start();

define('ROOT', realpath( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/');
set_include_path(ROOT . 'src/');

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors',  1); //To change in prod to 0 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
ini_set('log_errors',      1);
ini_set('error_log',       ROOT . 'tmp/logs/application.log');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

/*
 * Process stuff
 */

$params      = explode( '/', trim( key($_GET), '/' ) );
$paramsCount = count($params);

if ($paramsCount >= 2) {
  try {
    $controllerMethod = new ReflectionMethod( '\app\controller\\' .
                                                  $params[1], $params[2]
                                                );

    if ($paramsCount - 2 >= $controllerMethod->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()) {

      \ens\controller\Request::$lang =& $params[0];
      \ens\controller\Request::$data =& $_POST;

      $response = $controllerMethod->invokeArgs( null, array_splice($params, 3) );

    } else {
      $response = array('status' => 400);
    }

  } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
    $response = array('status' => 300);
  }

} else {
  $response = array('status' => 301);
}

if (!headers_sent()) {
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: You mean the class loader?

Comment: Yeah, you ask if it's efficient enough. Have you run into performance problems that would suggest that it isn't?

Comment: The problem with benchmarking a class loader is that the class is loaded only once. So I don't know in what kind of loop to put it! I am thinking about a shell benchmark or generating some thousands random classes and loading them all? Can one of these work better than another? I saw that the default spl_autoload() is making stat-ing files before loading.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, all the `ini_set` doesn't belong here, but in the php.ini, unless you can't edit it for some reasons…

If so, it belong in a [bootstrap file](http://www.serversidemagazine.com/php/bootstrap-php-code/), as for the constant definitions and the include

> A bootstrap file usually starts by including those libraries that are necessary for the file itself to function correctly. This involves setting general directory and file paths, loading configuration files, etc.

This bootstrap file can also be very useful for many reasons described on the link i provided like:

> […] set up different application statuses such as Development, Production or Testing […]

An other thing:

IMHO, the test `if (!headers_sent())` is pretty useless *as is*.

As you are returning JSON, you **need** to send this `header('Content-Type: application/json')`, so, if you can't for any reason, you should raise an error or an exception, not just doing nothing and echoing your JSON as if nothing happened…

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any useless parts. It's quite easy to read actually!

1. No validation at all of $_GET and $_POST? It doesn't look like namespaces support relative navigations, but that seems a bit dangerous, except if you can Always Trust User Input.
2. The "init stuff" could be put in another file and required.
3. ÉNS is a bit weird for an application name (private joke, sorry).

Comment: First, thank you for review. 1. Q: What is relative navigation[namespaces]? 2. Good for styling. 3. ENS is a acronym.

Comment: 1. \ens\controller\..\super_secret::DestroyEverything 3. I was thinking about the École Normale Supérieure, that's all. -- By the way, I don't have much to say, because I think it's quite good as it is.